# How to see or log each file that is loaded/accessed when a page loads?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

Is there a way with PHP or even IIS 7.5 to see exactly what files were accessed/loaded to render a page? For example, if a PHP page has 5 includes in it, I want to see exactly what those include files were.

Reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to fix a hacked site and I believe the hacked file is living outside of the website's files, but somewhere else on the server. I'vehad zero luck finding it and I'm hoping that if I can see exactly what files are being loaded/accessed when a page loads then that will help me track down where the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The web server wouldn't have anything to do with PHP includes but PHP includes a function called [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php).

At the end of your script, you could put:

```
var_dump(get_included_files());
```

Of course, a file doesn't have to be "included" to have executable code.  A file could be read and executed with [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) so you may consider disabling eval() if you don't use it anywhere.

Comment: Thats probably what to look for, `eval()` is more likely in compromised code.

Answer (score 0):

```
register_shutdown_function (function () {
    print_r(get_included_files());
});
```

This should tell you as soon as the script ends which files were used during execution.  I suggest dumping the result to a file.